# Relacionar duas tabelas mysql com dados da mesma coluna?

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Estou criando uma tabela da copa de 2014.

Criei duas tabelas.

```
times (ID, nome, sigla, bandeira)
jogos (ID, fase, local, time1_id, time2_id, data)
```

Estou com um problema relativamente simples, mas não achei solução pesquisando... Quero fazer um *Select* que me traga o nome do *time1* e do *time2* em uma consulta, substituindo o `ID`.

```
SELECT `jogos`.*, `time`.`nome` FROM `jogos` 
INNER JOIN `time` ON `jogos`.`time1_id` = `time`.`id` AND `jogos`.`time2_id` = `time`.`id`
```

Preciso de saber puxar o nome do *time1* e do *time2* através do `ID`..
Conseguiria fazer alguma gambiarra por PHP, como um *string replace*, mas gostaria de puxar pela tabela times os nomes.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa fazer `JOIN` novamente com a tabela times, exemplo:

```
SELECT
t.nome as time1,
t2.nome as time2
FROM times t
INNER JOIN jogos j
ON t.id = j.time1_id
INNER JOIN times t2
ON t2.id = j.time2_id
```

Exemplo: **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b030c/2)**

**Obs:** Exemplo minimalista para facilitar a compreensão.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que estava me faltando.. Eu não sabia que teria que fazer assim, nunca tinha caído nessa situação, agradeço muito pelo conhecimento que me trouxe. Resolvido!!

Comment: @Luther É isso aí, programando e aprendendo :)