# MySQL - Select entre 2 tabelas com campo "String"

Tags: mysql, sql, join

gostaria de saber como faço um Select para retornar o registros inexistentes, comparando duas tabelas com campo String.

Exemplo:

```
Tabelas Campo1   Campo2
Tab1    Nome     Tel
Tab2    Nome     email
```

O resultado da comparação (o select) seria somente os registros da Tab1 que não possuem o nome na Tab2

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Relacionar duas tabelas mysql com dados da mesma coluna?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20867/relacionar-duas-tabelas-mysql-com-dados-da-mesma-coluna)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Melhor forma**

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.nome FROM tabela2 t2 where t1.nome=t2.nome)
```

Comment: Tentei usar este exemplo mas deu erro.

Comment: Usei este código aqui e funcionou: 

`SELECT * FROM tab1 a`
`WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT nome FROM tab2 b `
`WHERE a.nome = b.nome);`
Agradeço a ajuda de todos pessoal!
Grande abraço!

Comment: Obrigado pela crítica construtiva @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade. Corrigi a resposta. Na hora de escrever acabei confundindo `NOT IN` com `NOT EXIST` e fiz confusão na `query`.

Answer (score 4):

Se o que você quer é trazer somente os nomes da `tabela 1` que não possuam correspondencia na `tabela 2`, voce pode fazer isso várias formas diferentes

Vou me ater somente nas sintaxes conformes ao SQL Ansi (válidos para todos os SGBDs listados nas tags)

## Usando o "left join"

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Tabela1 t1
left join Tabela2 t2 on t1.Nome=t2.Nome
where t2.nome is null
```

Veja funcionando do [SQLFiddle(MySQL 5.6)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90a567/2).

## Usando o predicado Exists

O predicado [`Exists`](http://trafodion.apache.org/docs/sql_reference/index.html#exists_predicate) é definido como:

> The EXISTS predicate determines whether any rows are selected by a
>   subquery. If the subquery finds at least one row that satisfies its
>   search condition, the predicate evaluates to true. Otherwise, if the
>   result table of the subquery is empty, the predicate is false.

Em tradução livre

> O predicado EXISTS determina se alguma linha é selecionada por uma subconsulta. Se a subconsulta encontrar pelo menos uma linha que satisfaça sua condição de pesquisa, o predicado será avaliado como verdadeiro. Caso contrário, se a tabela de resultados da subconsulta estiver vazia, o predicado é falso.

Neste caso específico:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela1 t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.nome FROM tabela2 t2 where t1.nome=t2.nome)
```

Veja funcionado no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90a567/3)

## Usando o Operador `IN`

Neste caso em particular, a operaçao é NOT IN:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela1 t1
WHERE  t1.nome NOT IN  (SELECT t2.nome FROM tabela2 t2)
```

Veja funcionado no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90a567/4)